# How to read a URL from a text file in python and return its content in a JSON format?

Tags: python, flask

I have a txt file containing URL. I want to read that text file and if it contains the URL read that URL and returns its content as a JSO, else return the contents of the text file if something else. My codes represent a FLASK application and I want to represent if as if elif else.

However, when I run the application it only shows me the URL itself not the contents of that URL.

However, when I run the application and click on the provided address, it shows me "true" and then opens a new tab and shows me connection error. I  expect, when I click on the link, it shows me the json content of the URL.

Could you please help me to fix it?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import json,re, requests
import webbrowser

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])

def test_function():
    with open('test1.txt',  encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as j:
    
        contents = j.read()
        #for line in contents:
        if re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', contents):
            for url in contents: 
                s = webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                return jsonify(s)
        else:
            return jsonify(contents)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: error indicates that your function didn't find any matching url, so add a "return "didn't find " at the end of test_function and try again.

Comment: I just revised the naming issues, however, the application does not working as i expect

Comment: It will be better if you can post the content of `test1.txt` file and your error traceback.